# PHP preg_replace without eval

Tags: php

Am trying to use something like:

```
$newdata = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $data);
```

Now my replacement is something like

```
$pattern = "/START(.*?)END/is";
$replacement = "START $config END";
```

Now, $config contains contents like

```
array('Test\\\'s Page')
```

The problem is that after I write the content, $newdata becomes

```
START array('Test\\'s Page') END
```

As you see above a single \ goes missing because it gets evaluated. How do I avoid that?

Comment: The \ don't get evaluated, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: the \\\' is getting converted to \\'. It is only after the preg_replace. If I echo $replacement and $newdata....

Comment: $config is a string and not an array. Those are just the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as expected... at least according to the [manual of preg_replace](http://www.php.net/preg_replace).

> To use backslash in replacement, it must be doubled ("\\\\" PHP string).

This is needed as you can use `\\n` for back references. If you don't want a back reference but want the `\` itself you need to escape it. If you want 3 backslashes you must write 6 backslashes.

```
$data = 'Some START END testdata';
$config = 'array(\'Test\\\\\\\\\\\\\'s Page\')';
$replacement = "START $config END";
$pattern = "/START(.*?)END/is";
var_dump($data, $config, $replacement, $pattern);
$newdata = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $data);
var_dump($newdata);
```

This will generate the following output.

```
string(23) "Some START END testdata"
string(26) "array('Test\\\\\\'s Page')"
string(36) "START array('Test\\\\\\'s Page') END"
string(17) "/START(.*?)END/is"
string(47) "Some START array('Test\\\'s Page') END testdata"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$replacement = "START".$config."END"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flattening the array into a string?

`$replacement = sprintf('START %s END', implode('', $config));`

EDIT: Since you did not mention what the `$config` looks like, we cannot give a definite answer.

Comment: I have mentioned what it looks like.